# How can to approach filtering for a period of time? What was the highest number of completed trips within a 24 hour period?

Tags: postgresql

I have this table that contains timestamps by the hour. The question is asking me to find x within y consecutive hours. How would I approach this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNxpg.png

Question: What was the highest number of completed trips within a 24 hour period?

Comment: Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide sample data, expected results, table DDL, and code demonstrating the issue. All of these should be in editable format within the question and not links to images or external resources. Show or describe what you've already tried.

Comment: The wording suggests that these are homework problems. Please clearly state in the question if such is the case. The community will be glad to offer guidance towards a better understanding of approaches and issues explored or encountered while solving a problem; however, please don't ask others to do the work for you. Posting code to show what has already been tried will make it easier for us to provide such guidance.

Comment: Sorry, I found some data that came with questions but not specifically for sql, nothing formal or bootcamp. Im not looking for a complete solution just the approach. How can I return data in intervals of time and compare them. The question is more of an example to better convey what i'm having trouble with.

Comment: I commend your efforts to expand your knowledge and suggest exploring window functions (especially with frames defined in `RANGE` mode) as a practical approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you commented that you are more interested in an approach vs. a full solution, I present the following which uses a window function with frames based on ranges. It should be easy to incorporate this into a full solution to answer the question "What was the highest number of completed trips within a 24 hour period?"

```
SELECT datetime,
       SUM(completed) OVER prior_24_hours   AS num_completed_prior_24_hours,
       SUM(requests) OVER prior_24_hours    AS num_requests_prior_24_hours,
       SUM(completed) OVER forward_24_hours AS num_completed_forward_24_hours,
       SUM(requests) OVER forward_24_hours  AS num_requests_forward_24_hours
  FROM t
WINDOW prior_24_hours AS (ORDER BY datetime RANGE '24H'::INTERVAL PRECEDING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),
       forward_24_hours AS (ORDER BY datetime RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '23H'::INTERVAL FOLLOWING);
```

The query uses named windows so that the declarations can be reused. Naming also acts as an executable comment describing the intent of the window declaration. For this example, the prior 24 hour summation is for the immediate 24 hour period preceding the current row's timestamp. Because the timestamps are guaranteed to be in discrete hours, the forward summation can be from the 0th through the 23rd hours. Had the timestamps had fractional seconds, then the query would need to be modified to exclude values from rows with timestamps exactly 24 hours after the current row's. One approach is to express the ending interval as `'23H59M59.999999S'::INTERVAL`; however, this approach depends on knowing the granularity of a timestamp and could eventually fail if the granularity changes. The following demonstrates an approach to excluding those values that avoids a dependence on the granularity:

```
SELECT datetime,
       SUM(completed) OVER prior_24_hours   AS num_completed_prior_24_hours,
       SUM(requests) OVER prior_24_hours    AS num_requests_prior_24_hours,
       SUM(completed) OVER forward_24_hours - SUM(completed) OVER exclude_24th_hour AS num_completed_forward_24_hours,
       SUM(requests) OVER forward_24_hours - SUM(requests) OVER exclude_24th_hour AS num_requests_forward_24_hours
  FROM t
WINDOW prior_24_hours AS (ORDER BY datetime RANGE '24H'::INTERVAL PRECEDING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW),
       forward_24_hours AS (ORDER BY datetime RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND '24H'::INTERVAL FOLLOWING),
       exclude_24th_hour AS (ORDER BY datetime RANGE BETWEEN '24H'::INTERVAL FOLLOWING AND '24H'::INTERVAL FOLLOWING);
```

One of the columns, `unique_drivers`, cannot be handled reliably by this approach because there isn't any way to determine which drivers are included in each row's data.